# Character Lowercase to Uppercase in Shell Scripting

Tags: unix

I have value as:
**james,adam,john**
I am trying to make it **James,Adam,John**(First character of each name should be Uppercase)

According to kev(below),

$ echo 'james,adam,john' | sed 's/\<./\u&/g'
James,Adam,John(It is not working in all the systems)

I am not able to do the same thing in different system.I am using .ksh, but I don't know whether its because of ksh or different system. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
$ echo 'james,adam,john' | sed 's/\<./\u&/g'
James,Adam,John
```

- pattern `\<.` will match first char of every word
- use `\u&` to make it uppercase.

Comment: In which basis (\<.)its knowing the first character?

Comment: `\<` will match word boundary.

Comment: This is a GNU sed extension though, so you're lucky you have that version.

Comment: yes  lynxlynxlynx, I agree with you. I am not able to do the same thing in different system.I am using .ksh, but I don't know whether its because of ksh or different system. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2):

Using bash:

```
A="james adam john"
B=( $A )
echo "${B[@]^}"
```

Output is:

```
James Adam John
```

Answer (score 1):

There are endless possibilities, but look up `tr` and shell string substitution (if your shell supports it). Then there's GNU `sed`, awk, perl and many other languages ...