# Lowercase to Uppercase of character in Shell Scripting

Tags: perl, shell, unix, sed, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Character Lowercase to Uppercase in Shell Scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210568/character-lowercase-to-uppercase-in-shell-scripting)

I have value as: `james,adam,john` I am trying to make it `James,Adam,John` (First character of each name should be Uppercase).

```
echo 'james,adam,john' | sed 's/\<./\u&/g'
```

is not working in all the systems. In one system its showing ok..but not ok in another system...

```
A="james adam john"
B=( $A )
echo "${B[@]^}"
```

its throwing some syntax error...So, i am doing it through a long query sing while loop, which is too lengthy.
Is there any shortcut way to do this?

Comment: on which systems does your code work and on which does it not.

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways to define "beginning of a name". This method chooses any letter after a word boundary and transforms it to upper case. As a side effect, this will also work with names such as "Sue Ellen", or "Billy-Bob".

```
echo "james,adam,john" | perl -pe 's/(\b\pL)/\U$1/g'
```

Answer (score 3):

With Perl:

```
echo "james,adam,john" | \
  perl -ne 'print  join(",", map{ ucfirst } split(/,/))'
```

Comment: Thanks perreal, It's working in my present system, Let me try in my required system.

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk like this to capitalize first letter of every word in your input:

```
echo "james,adam,john" | awk 'BEGIN { RS=","; FS=""; ORS=","; OFS=""; }
{ $1=toupper($1); print $0; }'
```

#### OUTPUT

```
James,Adam,John
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava, It's working in my present system, Let me try in my required system.

Answer (score 1):

Same method as *TLP* but with GNU sed:

```
echo "james,adam,john,sue ellen,billy-bob" | sed -r 's/\b(.)/\u\1/g'
```

output:

```
James,Adam,John,Sue Ellen,Billy-Bob
```

If only the first letter should be capitalized, use this instead:

```
echo "james,adam,john,sue ellen,billy-bob" | sed 's/[^,]*/\u&/g'
```

output:

```
James,Adam,John,Sue ellen,Billy-bob
```